# How to access the data returned by roles by factory in the controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http) {
var serviceurl = 'http://localhost:12345/Area/Controller/Action/';
var roles = [];
function getRole(id) {
    //alert(id);
    $http.get(serviceurl + id).success(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        roles = data;
    })
    .error(function (x, y) {
        alert('error occurred');
    });
}
return {
    roles: roles 
}
});
```

I am calling it in my controller as:

```
app.controller("myController", function ($scope, $http, myService) {
    $scope.roles = myService.roles;
});
```

but $scope.roles is undefined and myService.roles has no value: roles[] when I tried to place a breakpoint in $scope.roles = myService.roles;

What is wrong with my code?How should I call roles in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.factory('myService', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getRole:function(id){
            var serviceurl = 'http://localhost:12345/Area/Controller/Action/';
            var roles = [];
            var p = $q.defer();
            $http.get(serviceurl + id).success(function(data) {         
                console.log(data);              
                p.resolve(data);
            })
            .error(function (x, y) {
                alert('error occurred');
            });
            return p.promise;
        }
    }   
});
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.roles = myService.getRole(id);
```

Comment: I am getting the same results when I used this code. $scope.roles is still undefined. Please advise further on what may be the reason why $scope.roles becomes undefined.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?